# How to Create Color Status When Pending/Approval/Disapprove

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm planning to create a status notification. Example, whenever the information is

```
"Pending", it turns to color orange.
When "Approved" it turns to color green and when 
its "Disapproved", it turns to color red
```

I've created a "status" column in every data that is submitted. So, when I call the value. Here's my code

```
while($objstat = $query->fetch_object()){
  echo "Status: ".$objstat->status;
}
```

I want to put bootstrap danger,success,info etc as the color of the status. Please any help there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `if/else` condition to do it. Btw what is returning in `$objstat->status`?

Try the sample below

```
<?php
while($objstat = $query->fetch_object())
{
    //echo "Status: ".$objstat->status;
    if($objstat->status == "Approved")
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Well done! Pending Message.
            </div>';
    }
    else if($objstat->status == "Pending")
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                Warning! Pending Message.
            </div>';
    }
    else if($objstat->status == "Disapproved")
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                Danger! Disapproved Message.
            </div>';
    }
}
?>
```